# How to disable a view script in a controller - Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, view

I am playing with zend framework's MVC. One thing I found out is that Zend Framework tries to include a view script whenever a controller is called. I can disable it in bootstrap with the following code.

$frontController->setParam('noViewRenderer',true);

However, I have to initialize Zend_View class in a controller method then render a script file myself.

How can I stop including a view script in a controller method so I can disable it if only I want to?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can disable the view renderer controller helper, with this code in your controller:

```
public function myAction()
{
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    // from now on, ZF won't search for a matching view script file.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The best example would be to use both commands above:

```
public function myAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
}
```

First one disables layout,in general is enabled

> application.ini

default

> resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"

`$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();`

and second disables view script (.phtml) so exception is not thrown if view script file is not found

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

There are also view helpers that include bouth listened abowe and are not necessary, for example you want to return JSON from array data and not render view element.

```
public function myAction() {
    $this->_helper->json(array());
}
```

will not render layout nor view script.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just disable it from within your action.

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

If you aren't talking about layouts, then just add an exit() to your action. Just understand what sort of impact that will have on your application.

Comment: that is not what I was asking, but that is helpful as well!!